# How to Remove rancid smells from clothes closet

Tags: cleaning, home, clothing, smell

My husband canned bacon several years ago and unbeknownst to me placed 6 quart size jars of this on the top shelf of our shared closet and basically forgot about them.  Today when I walked into the closet I was met with a horrific smell that nearly made me .  Long story short, my husband produces these 6 jars with one having a build up of smelly gunk on the outside of the jar.  All 6 jars are now in the garbage outside but the smell in the closet is still there .  I’ve tried washing down the area where the jars were sitting with bleach and soap and water.  The smell is still in closet. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Only the closet still has the smell? You managed to take it out of the cloths themselves?

Answer (score 2):

"Pink Solution" is a natural enzyme based cleaner. If you wish to remove organic based residue you should use an enzyme based cleaner because they continue working after application to actively attack and grow off remaining bacteria. so unlike lysol spray or other chemical solutions it won't just kill everything, it will specifically target organic scents and residue and actively remove it even after application.

Would recommend using an essential oil in your mix since pink solution, for the most part,  has no scent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe spray with Febreeze (https://www.febreze.com/en-us).